# Red neuronal con propagacion hacia atras devuelve las mismas salidas para vectores de gran tamaño

Tags: python, redes-neuronales, inteligencia-artificial

Tengo un problema con la red neuronal de propagación hacia atrás, está escrita en `Python`, aquí dejo el [enlace de GitHub](https://github.com/mattm/simple-neural-network/blob/master/neural-network.py) (en inglés), con un vector de 4096 entradas, 2 neuronas de capa oculta y 197 neuronas de salidas.

Pongo la red a entrenar y una vez finalizado el entrenamiento hago la clasificación con otros vectores de 4096 entradas de prueba. Resulta que esos vectores tienen distintos valores de entradas y tendrían que devolver diferentes valores salidas y no es así, devuelven siempre los mismos valores de salida (vectores de 197 elementos con iguales valores).

Probando con vectores de menor tamaño (por ejemplo 10) devuelve distintas salidas, pero al aumentar el tamaño del vector, las salidas se van asemejando hasta igualarse.

Alguien tiene idea de como solucionar este problema. Necesito procesar vectores de 4096 elementos, gracias.

Acá dejo un código de ejemplo con 6 inputs de 50 elementos para un objeto que está representado por la salida `[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`. Luego yo clasifico 5 vectores con elementos al azar:

```
import neural-network as red
ERROR = 0.01
from random import randint, choice
training_sets=[]
inputs = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,2,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
for i in inputs:
    training_sets.append([i,[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]) # Entrada y salida de la red neuronal para un objeto
r = red.NeuralNetwork(len(training_sets[0][0]), 2,len(training_sets[0][1]))
i=0
while r.calculate_total_error(training_sets)>=ERROR:
   training_inputs, training_outputs = choice(training_sets)
   r.train(training_inputs, training_outputs) #Entrenar la red Neuronal
   print(str(i), r.calculate_total_error(training_sets))
   i=i+1 

vectorPrueba=[] #Vector de prueba a clasificar
for j in range(0, 5):
  for i in range(0, 50):
     vectorPrueba.append(randint(0,2)) #Completo con valores 0,1 y 2 al azar
  salida = r.feed_forward(vectorPrueba)
  vectorPrueba = []
  print salida #Devuelve la salida de cada vector
```

Luego de terminar la ejecución los 5 vectores de salida que me devuelve son los siguientes:

> [0.9854057188339234, 0.016461838771138552, 0.017103414498752866, 0.016732153465498976, 0.01674068815079351, 0.016485508202722498, 0.016624436927601596, 0.01697716105043288, 0.01710824193364747, 0.016851276127026776]
>
> [0.9854057188329309, 0.01646183877244117, 0.017103414499968748, 0.01673215346622041, 0.016740688151502595, 0.016485508203670583, 0.01662443692859318, 0.016977161051286285, 0.0171082419345771, 0.016851276128414153]
>
> [0.9854057188334164, 0.016461838771695332, 0.017103414499274005, 0.01673215346557889, 0.016740688150914253, 0.01648550820299679, 0.01662443692790807, 0.016977161050612977, 0.017108241933953106, 0.016851276127679213]
>
> [0.9854057188341665, 0.016461838770744055, 0.017103414498399316, 0.01673215346509605, 0.016740688150327837, 0.01648550820233476, 0.016624436927245422, 0.016977161050000102, 0.017108241933327245, 0.016851276126710966]
>
> [0.9854057188340861, 0.01646183877084542, 0.017103414498492647, 0.016732153465146303, 0.01674068815039041, 0.016485508202404575, 0.01662443692731513, 0.016977161050064624, 0.01710824193339344, 0.016851276126814193]
>
> [0.9854057188330729, 0.016461838772193094, 0.017103414499723312, 0.016732153465959795, 0.0167406881513114, 0.016485508203417144, 0.01662443692831659, 0.016977161051037217, 0.017108241934303412, 0.016851276128148848]

Como pueden observar, las salidas, son muy similares. Si uso vectores de 4096 las salidas son iguales, a eso es lo que me refiero.

Comment: Sin conocer más información de cómo son los *inputs*, que esperas que represente el *output*,..., es difícil saber mucho más. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo reproducible que muestre lo que te está pasando? Parece un caso de sobreajuste pero si no das más información...

Comment: La red la estoy utilizando para reconocimientos de objetos. Los inputs son representaciones de imagenes de objetos que estan compuestas por 0, 1 y 2. y la salida representa el objeto al que pertenece (en total 197 objetos). Por ejemplo si proceso la imagen de un perro la entrada es un vector de 4096 que representa las características de la imagen por ejemplo [1,0,2,1,1,1,1,0,2...] y la salida esta compuesta por un 1 (que representa el objeto en cuestión) y todos 0 por ejemplo [1,0,0,0,0,0...]

Comment: Una red neuronal en que todos los pesos y sesgos valen 0 devolvería siempre el mismo valor para todas las entradas. Igualmente un fallo en la programación podría provocar efectos similares. Sin un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) es muy difícil descubrir el problema. Te sugiero poner el mínimo código necesario para reproducir el error así como un enlace de descarga de archivos ejemplo de las entradas que usas.

Comment: Ahí arriba lo complete con un ejemplo, espero que sirva, gracias

Answer (score 1):

No se que herramienta utilices yo uso neurolab (https://pythonhosted.org/neurolab/), cuando me sucede algo parecido por lo general aumento las neuronas de la capa oculta, otra cosa es que la función de activación, en neurolab necesita entradas de 0 a 1 o de -1 a 1 dependiendo de la función de activación, por lo que se necesitan normalizar las entradas. Cuando no se normalizan sucede lo que tu describes.